# What do you call people who are obsessed with time?

Tags: time

When you never know what time it is, and your family thinks it's polite to show up early.

Comment: Which is your question?

Answer (score 0):

A word that may address the headline of your question is [chronomania](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chronomania):

> **chronomania** *n* (Greek khronos, time + Greek mania, obsession, madness;
>   cf. megalomania, balletomania) - obsession with time and speed;
>   inclination to utilize every moment and to submit one's life to a
>   total time control.

However, from the body of your question, I infer that your family is simply [*punctual*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/punctual#punctual__1), while you are inclined to be [*tardy*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tardy_1).

> **punctual**, *adj*. arriving or happening at the time agreed on
>
> **tardy**, *adj*. 1. slow to do something; 2. arriving late

Comment: add citations to your choices

Comment: This does not correspond at all to an obsession.

Comment: @lbf Are the links in my answer not apparent?

Comment: @Gnawme my bad! apologies.

Comment: @Gnawme References [MUST be visible in plain text](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). SE data may appear without link destinations.